# Converting Hex Number in MIPS Instruction, how to find out if I or R type?

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, mips, opcode

Hey guys I already know basically how to convert a hex number in a mips instruction. The thing is if I convert it to binary how do I quickly check if its an R type or I type instruction?

R type uses 6 bits for opcode, 5 for rs, rt, rd, shift amount and 6 for function code

I type uses 6 for opcode, 5 for rt and rs, but 16 bit for immediate amount.

So when I convert my hex number, how do I know fast if the last 16 bit are for an immediate value or and rd, shift amount and function code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I already got the answer. Just look at the opcode. Dude needed some time to get that.

Comment: Glad to see this. So, please mark the question as solved (your own answer as accepted one).